# Converting frames of raw video to Inverse Perspective Mapped frames

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, perspective

I have a raw video of 1000 frames.I am doing Inverse Perspective Mapping of these frames and storing these frames on hard disk. But this process takes around 10 minutes to convert it.
Is there any other way in which speed can be improved? I am using CVWarpPerspective and cvgetperspectivetransform functions, I have to do it in real time with a maximum delay of 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenGL for hardware acceleration; but your biggest bottleneck is likely to be writing the images back to disk.

Assuming the images aren't small; half a second to load, warp and save 1000 raw frames is very demanding. What is the reason for this specification ?

Comment: I need it for signs on roads detection system.

Comment: Can't you calculate the perspective transform and only interpolate the image when you need to; then you would not have to save the warped images.